# pytest: TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

Tags: python, pytest, solidity, brownie

```
def _get_trace(self) -> None:
    """Retrieves the stack trace via debug_traceTransaction and finds the
    return value, revert message and event logs in the trace.
    """

    # check if trace has already been retrieved, or the tx warrants it
    if self._raw_trace is not None:
        return
    self._raw_trace = []
    if self.input == "0x" and self.gas_used == 21000:
        self._modified_state = False
        self._trace = []
        return

    if not web3.supports_traces:
        raise RPCRequestError("Node client does not support `debug_traceTransaction`")
    try:
        trace = web3.provider.make_request(  # type: ignore
            "debug_traceTransaction", (self.txid, {"disableStorage": CONFIG.mode != "console"})
        )
    except (requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as e:
        msg = f"Encountered a {type(e).__name__} while requesting "
        msg += "`debug_traceTransaction`. The local RPC client has likely crashed."
        if CONFIG.argv["coverage"]:
            msg += " If the error persists, add the `skip_coverage` marker to this test."
        raise RPCRequestError(msg) from None

    if "error" in trace:
        self._modified_state = None
        self._trace_exc = RPCRequestError(trace["error"]["message"])
        raise self._trace_exc

    self._raw_trace = trace = trace["result"]["structLogs"]
    if not trace:
        self._modified_state = False
        return

    # different nodes return slightly different formats. its really fun to handle
    # geth/nethermind returns unprefixed and with 0-padding for stack and memory
    # erigon returns 0x-prefixed and without padding (but their memory values are like geth)
    fix_stack = False
    for step in trace:
        if not step["stack"]:
            continue
        check = step["stack"][0]
        if not isinstance(check, str):
            break
        if check.startswith("0x"):
            fix_stack = True

> c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\transaction.py(678)_get_trace()
-> step["pc"] = int(step["pc"], 16)
(Pdb)
```

I am doing Patricks Solidity course and ran into this error. I ended up copying and pasting his code:

```
def test_only_owner_can_withdraw():
    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        pytest.skip("only for local testing")
    fund_me = deploy_fund_me()
    bad_actor = accounts.add()
    with pytest.raises(exceptions.VirtualMachineError):
        fund_me.withdraw({"from": bad_actor})
```

Pytest worked for my other tests however When I tried to do this one it wouldnt work.

Comment: not quite sure I understand, are you getting an error only when debugging? not when running the program?

Comment: Im getting the error when running: 'brownie test' in the terminal.
Im getting no errors when I run: 'brownie test' on other tests. Only for the example above.
I started the debugger only to find where the issue was coming from

Comment: is that your code the _get_trace()? haha a bit confusing since it is about stack traces.. the error tells you if that is the case that `step['pc']` is not a string have you for example done "print step" before tha erraneous line, or in the debugger seen what it looks like

Comment: nah its not my code at all haha. Yesterday I ran into an error with web3 and after research, I found I needed to change encode_xxx to just encode and then I ran into this. I tried to search through the whole code to find what 'pc' was referring to but no luck. its used in the exact same format in other places however it is only flagged on that line

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So after looking at my scripts and contracts I found the issue. The was an issue with my .sol contract and instead of returning a variable, it was returning the error message from my retrieve function in the contract. Its fixed and working now